How can I design a turing machine that recognises this language? 01^n01^n0
I keep on struggling with how to actually capture the number of 0's .
Do I use a different marker to capture 0 and 1? Or do I need to create new states that count the number of 0's? This doesn't seem particuarly elegant to me, but I don't see anyway to count exactly 3 0's. Also when I back track to recount the number of 1's, how do I know when I reach the start?

Take a two-tape TM, use the second tape as a stack to check the number of ones.

Is there any way I can just use one TM? Or is it required for me to use a two tape?

A multi-tape TM can always be transformed to single-tape, but the result will be awkward.

For a single-tape design maybe: check that the input is in the form 01^m01^n0 (m, n not necessarily equal), that should be simple enough. Then make passes that delete one 1 from the first island of ones and one from the second. Accept if at the end you have no ones left over.

Or you could do: accept 000, else find a 101 subsequence and rewrite it to 0 and move the rest of the tape by two. Restart.

How would I go about this then if I added a 1^n0 to the end?


Do I use a different marker to capture 0 and 1?

No need for different markers. You can erase 1s by replacing them by 0s in a controlled way.

Or do I need to create new states that count the number of 0's?

Yes.

This doesn't seem particularly elegant to me

That is a matter of opinion, but using different states is the way to go.

Also when I back track to recount the number of 1's

You don't actually count the number of 1's. Instead you pair each 1 in the left half with another 1 in the right half.

...how do I know when I reach the start?

In the very first state you'll have asserted that the first character was a 0, so now when backtracking you know you'll have reached the start when you encounter a (third) zero. Again, you'd use different states on your way back to keep track of which zero you have already encountered.
You could solve this in two phases:

Check whether the input has exactly three 0's, assuming the input is followed by a blank (not part of the input)

Go back and forth over the tape and each time replace the outermost 1 by a 0 until there are no more 1s that can be paired that way. In that case you can conclude whether the original had the desired pattern.


First phase:



current state
symbol read
symbol to write
head moves to
new state




start
0
copy
right
toSecond0


start
1,blank
copy
right
reject


toSecond0
0
copy
right
toThird0


toSecond0
1
copy
right
toSecond0


toSecond0
blank
copy
right
reject


toThird0
0
copy
right
assertBlank


toThird0
1
copy
right
toThird0


toThird0
blank
copy
right
reject


assertBlank
blank
copy
left
atThird0


assertBlank
0,1
copy
left
reject



Second phase starts at state atThird0 with the head on the final zero.



current state
symbol read
symbol to write
head moves to
new state




atThird0
0
copy
left
wipeToLeft


wipeToLeft
0
copy
left
assert0


wipeToLeft
1
0
left
toCenterLeft


assert0
0
copy
left
accept


assert0
1
copy
left
reject


toCenterLeft
0
copy
left
toStart


toCenterLeft
1
copy
left
toCenterLeft


toStart
0
copy
right
wipeToRight


toStart
1
copy
left
toStart


wipeToRight
0
copy
right
reject


wipeToRight
1
0
right
toCenterRight


toCenterRight
0
copy
right
toEnd


toCenterRight
1
copy
right
toCenterRight


toEnd
0
copy
right
wipeToLeft


toEnd
1
copy
right
toEnd



Here is an implementation of a Turing machine in JavaScript, and it is run with the above transition table. You can play with the input to see what you get:


createTuring({
  transitions: [
    { state: "start"         , read: "0"             , move: "R", nextState: "toSecond0" },
    { state: "start"         , read: "1_"            , move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "toSecond0"     , read: "0"             , move: "R", nextState: "toThird0" },
    { state: "toSecond0"     , read: "1"             , move: "R", nextState: "toSecond0" },
    { state: "toSecond0"     , read: "_"             , move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "toThird0"      , read: "0"             , move: "R", nextState: "assertBlank" }, 
    { state: "toThird0"      , read: "1"             , move: "R", nextState: "toThird0" },
    { state: "toThird0"      , read: "_"             , move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "assertBlank"   , read: "_"             , move: "L", nextState: "atThird0" },
    { state: "assertBlank"   , read: "01"            , move: "L", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "atThird0"      , read: "0"             , move: "L", nextState: "wipeToLeft" },
    { state: "wipeToLeft"    , read: "0"             , move: "L", nextState: "assert0" },
    { state: "wipeToLeft"    , read: "1", write: "0" , move: "L", nextState: "toCenterLeft" },
    { state: "assert0"       , read: "0"             , move: "L", nextState: "accept" },
    { state: "assert0"       , read: "1"             , move: "L", nextState: "reject" }, 
    { state: "toCenterLeft"  , read: "0"             , move: "L", nextState: "toStart" },
    { state: "toCenterLeft"  , read: "1"             , move: "L", nextState: "toCenterLeft" },
    { state: "toStart"       , read: "0"             , move: "R", nextState: "wipeToRight" },
    { state: "toStart"       , read: "1"             , move: "L", nextState: "toStart" },
    { state: "wipeToRight"   , read: "0"             , move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "wipeToRight"   , read: "1", write: "0" , move: "R", nextState: "toCenterRight" },
    { state: "toCenterRight" , read: "0"             , move: "R", nextState: "toEnd" },
    { state: "toCenterRight" , read: "1"             , move: "R", nextState: "toCenterRight" },
    { state: "toEnd"         , read: "0"             , move: "L", nextState: "wipeToLeft" },
    { state: "toEnd"         , read: "1"             , move: "R", nextState: "toEnd" }
  ],
  initState: "start",
  tape: "01111011110",
});
<script src="https://trincot.github.io/turing.js"></script>




@johnjones, do you have any feedback to this answer?
